# Dotnet Core build Intermediate Container Removed

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, containers

Hi Folks I am trying to containerized standard Asp dotnet core application with Dockerfile generated by Visual Studio.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dotnetcoredokc/dotnetcoredokc.csproj", "dotnetcoredokc/"]
RUN dotnet restore "dotnetcoredokc/dotnetcoredokc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/dotnetcoredokc"
RUN dotnet build "dotnetcoredokc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "dotnetcoredokc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetcoredokc.dll"]
```

After long wait I have received this error.

```
e4c3d3e4f7b0: Pull complete
101c41d0463b: Pull complete
8275efcd805f: Pull complete
751620502a7a: Pull complete
8e306865fd07: Pull complete
9d2f53e752c2: Pull complete
143a93e01eba: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bfd6083e9cd36b37b2a4e9f1722cc958b6654fa96cb3d84ef78492ecf00dcd32
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
---> 5fe503d51830
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /src
---> Running in 2645ba31f404
Removing intermediate container 2645ba31f404
---> ba24bc746a28
Step 7/17 : COPY ["dotnetcoredokc/dotnetcoredokc.csproj", "dotnetcoredokc/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder187253264/dotnetcoredokc/dotnetcoredokc.csproj: no such file or directory
```

Comment: The file `dotnetcoredokc/dotnetcoredokc.csproj` is not found within Docker's context. On your filesystem, does that file exists (in reference to the Dockerfile)? I find the autogenerated Dockerfile doesn't work well if you have a different solution layout than what VS expects.

Comment: Yes I have this csproj file in project.